# How to access object in ActionResult<object> or routeValues from CreatedAtAction() return in .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a Controller method with the following code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Project>> Create(Project project)
{
    project.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    project.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    project.CreatedAtSystemUserId = new Guid();
    project.UpdatedAtSystemUserId = new Guid();

    Context.Projects.Add(project);
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetProject", new { id = project.ProjectId }, project);
}
```

And I am calling the `Create()` method from a Blazor component:

```
protected async void BtnSaveProject_Click()
{
    var response = await ProjectService.Create(Project);
    var project = response.Result.Value;

    // NagivationManagerHelper.NavigateTo(string.Format("/projects/{0}", project.ProjectId.ToString()));
}
```

When I try to reference `response.Result.Value` InteliSense is telling me that ActionResult has no definition for Value, yet when I run this code through debugger and inspect `response` I can see that `Result` has `Value`.  Why can't I reference it in code?

Comment: Have you tried accessing it like response.Result["Value"]? if "Value" is a dynamic object's property, it might not be part of the object as it is.

Comment: I just did, and IntelliSense is saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ActionResult'".  Additionally, the build is failing with the same error :(  I've tried await ProjectService.Create(Project).Result.Value, but i get an error about Project not having a definition of 'GetAwaiter'.

Comment: Why can't I reference it in code? Because compiler doesn't know what is the actual type of `ActionResult` all it knows is that the current type for this object is `ActionResult` and this type doesn't contain `Value`.

Comment: Why do your service create an ActionResult? should it be a plain `Project`? Your service acts like a controller

Answer (score -1):

CreateAtAction() returns with type [CreatedAtActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.createdatactionresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can access its value directly by

```cs
var response = await ProjectService.Create(Project);
var project = response.Value;
```

Comment: I actually originally tried that, however, `response.Value` is always null.  All the data resides in `response.Result`.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry. Returning the result as `ActionResult<Project>` complicates the things a bit. However, I was able to get the proper value from `response.Result.Result.Value`

Comment: You cannot access the Result.Result.Value. This statement is false.